# Where is the C++ profiler in Netbeans 7.1.2

Tags: c++, netbeans, profiler

Netbeans 6.9 had a profiler facility for C++ (we had to install the sun studio to use it).
However, I cannot find the C++ profiler in netbeans 7.1. The sun studio 12.3 has already installed and works with netbeans 7.1. I also cannot find the "profile" section in the c++ project properties in NB 7.1 while that existed in NB 6.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the Netbeans 7.1 release notes, the C/C++ Profiling Tools were removed from the standard distribution of the IDE.

link to the release notes:  http://netbeans.org/community/releases/71/relnotes.html