# Netbeans 8 c++ profiler or tools/plugins to help find bottlenecks in code? (for linux)

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, profiler

I'm developing a project in C++ using Netbeans and I just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11496188/2414842) answer which says that the Netbeans profiler for this language was removed from the IDE, unfortunately. Is there any other thing that I can use to search for bottlenecks in my code on netbeans? Maybe in the IDE itself or maybe some plugin... Anything that helps me to measure the time consumed by the procedures, etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Independent of Netbeans: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/23512/101

Comment: Thanks, but it's not available to linux

Comment: [*Try this.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) There's a video [*here*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPg3sRpdW1U).

Comment: @Fabiotk:  The instrumenter/display part of the tool runs fine under Wine on Linux; works with GCC4/5.   Your instrumented code runs under Linux as you expect.